# Has the phasing out of the mobile specific site in main areas begun?

Tags: discussion, design

I recall reading a meta post some time ago that the mobile version of SO was going away, set to be replaced by a responsive version of the regular site. I note as I write this question the edit box is different (more controls) so perhaps meta got it early (though I seldom ask questions on the main site) but chiefly the main question list now looks quite different to a tag question list:

> [image]

What I recognize as "the mobile site":

> [image]

The new question listing feels a little more cluttered and wordy than the old; the separation of the voting/answering blobs into a dedicated column helps scan the question titles, and the text of the question title is much less prominent now; to me it seems like it's getting lost in amongst what is (for me) largely irrelevant detail

The edit box is a slight concern; the shift to mono space is welcome (though the preview is equally helpful), as it'll mean I don't have to count when I'm doing some preformatted text, but the new edit box holds considerably less content than the old:

> [image]

Old:

> [image]

---

It's usable but I hope it is "still being developed" and if the UI team could make sure a good amount of mobile use of the new design occurs it'd be helpful. In the past it felt like the mobile experience was overlooked in terms of new features somewhat but that became welcome in terms of keeping the mobile site nimble and workable on limited devices.

I'm curious mostly about the shift towards "use more text" when it seems a lot of UI design shifts towards "use more iconography" for internationalization and simplicity reasons.. On a smaller screen I don't personally find loading the main screen up with text and sparsing out the text editor is the right way round..

Comment: It has begun a long time ago (see changes to profile, etc.) but the (legacy) mobile design is still accessible. What you're seeing here (on the home page) is just the recent changes to the responsive design of questions lists. See: [New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/348196). It's awful but the first iteration of this was even worse. Just scan the recent posts on MSO and MSE and you'll see a lot of negative feedback about it.

Comment: To be honest, for me, the new UI looks great on mobile– but that's the double-edged sword. What looks good or fine on mobile does _not_ necessarily _look good on desktop_.

Comment: I am personally not a fan of the legacy mobile styles disappearing. The main page / top questions went away earlier this week, and individual question pages just today. I appreciate the desire to streamline their codebase (and gaining dark mode is cool), but I have all the same complaints you do. Unused whitespace, jumbled-together text... it's just way less useable (on mobile) than it was.